# ERROR: function pg_catalog.extract(unknown, integer) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, partitioning

I am writing an SQL query for creating the partitions which looks like:

```
DO
$$
    DECLARE
        table_name             text     := 'table_1';
        start_date             date     := (SELECT MIN(create_date)
                                            FROM db.table);
        end_date               date     := (SELECT MAX(create_date)
                                            FROM db.table);
        partition_interval     interval := '1 day';
        partition_column_value text;
    BEGIN
        FOR partition_column_value IN SELECT start_date +
                                             (generate_series * extract(day from partition_interval)::integer)::date
                                      FROM generate_series(0, extract(day from end_date - start_date::date) /
                                                              extract(day from partition_interval))
            LOOP
                EXECUTE format(
                        'create table if not exists %1$s_%2$s partition of %1$s for values in (%2$s) partition by list (create_date)',
                        table_name, partition_column_value::date);
            END LOOP;
    END
$$;
```

I get an error:

```
[42883] ERROR: function pg_catalog.extract(unknown, integer) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 9 at FOR over SELECT rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error msg is this:

```
extract(day from end_date - start_date::date)
```

It's nonsense to cast `start_date::date`, `start_date` being type `date` to begin with. More importantly, `date - date` yields `integer` (not `interval` like you might assume). And [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) does not operate on integer input.

I removed more confusion and noise to arrive at this:

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   table_name             text    := 'table_1';
   partition_interval     integer := 1;  -- given in days!!
   start_date             date;
   end_date               date;
   partition_column_value text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO start_date, end_date  -- two assignments for the price of one
          min(create_date), max(create_date)
   FROM   db.table;
   
   FOR partition_column_value IN
      SELECT start_date + g * partition_interval         -- date + int → date
      FROM   generate_series(0, (end_date - start_date)  -- date - date → int
                              / partition_interval) g
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format(
         'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %1$I PARTITION OF %1$I
          FOR VALUES IN (%3$L) PARTITION BY LIST (create_date)'
        , table_name || to_char(partition_column_value, '"_"yyyymmdd')  -- !
        , table_name
        , partition_column_value::text  -- only covers single day!!
          );
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

This should *work*.
**But** it only makes sense for the example interval of '1 day'. For longer intervals, concatenate the list of days per partition or switch to range partitioning ...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using date_part function in pg

```
     .......
        DATE_PART('day', date_end::timestamp - date_start ::timestamp) as xxxx``
```